# The LaTeX sandbox question is crashing the page

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

In Chrome, the EE.SE LaTeX test page crashes the tab. Link below:

[Test the new LaTeX markdown in this Sandbox question!](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question)

The page partially loads (at least everything near the top for me), and then I'm presented with an error message:

[image: I'm getting a stack overflow on StackOverflow]

It doesn't look like the question or answers have been recently edited, but there's also no indication how long this has been the case. Thanks to @rdtsc for bringing it up.

Comment: "STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW".... hahaha

Comment: The irony was not lost on me :)

Comment: Works in Firefox 87.0 but crash in Chrome Version 89.0.4389.114 (and if you've got the developer tools console open, it says "DevTools was disconnected from the page"). Firefox console says Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js”. and utils.js errors “veryverythinmathspace”, “verythinmathspace”, “thinmathspace”, “mediummathspace”, “thickmathspace”, “verythickmathspace” and “veryverythickmathspace” are deprecated values for MathML lengths and will be removed at a future date.

Comment: The [gamedev](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mathjax-latex-in-posts-has-been-added-lets-make-some-math)  and [codereview](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10638/mathjax-is-really-eager-to-be-applied-to-posts) mathjax sandbox meta questions are displayed correctly... seems like the issue is limited to electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: See also [which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

Comment: LaTex / mathjax is displayed correctly in existing qa e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537091/are-the-two-op-amp-terminals-at-equal-bias-for-positive-feedback/537104#537104

Comment: I put it under review, we'll see what happens.

Comment: Similar behavior in the Opera browser (no go.)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there is *something* in one of the LaTeX statements on that page that can hard crash a browser.... but it's hard to figure out what that is when it's crashing the whole page. If nothing else, this is poorly-managed user input that could be used to sabotage a page.

Comment: Dunno if it's something on our end, or potentially a bug _on Chrome_, but I was able to repro, and will have a dev look into it as a part of bug duty.

Comment: Thanks @JNat! In the short term, is there something we can do (e.g. remove part of a question/answer) to stop the crashing on that specific page?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. If I knew which answer was causing it, we could temporarily edit it, but since the answer below points out that no specific answer seems to be causing this... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Had a dev look into this, @W5VO, and it looks like there's nothing that jumps out as the cause of this. We can either just delete this sandbox post and create a new one, or alternatively selectively delete and undelete answers on Firefox and seeing how that affects the page's performance on Chrome — potentially by doing so we'd be able to identify the set of answers causing this, and fix those (or keep 'em deleted). I'm inclined to take the former option, since it's easier... thoughts?

Comment: @JNat Deleting the original MathJax sandbox question sounds fine from a pragmatic perspective.

Comment: I'm marking this as [tag:status-completed], then, @W5VO — will leave creating the new post and deleting the old one to you, unless you tell me otherwise (though I think it'd be more appropriate for you to do it).

Comment: @JNat I can make a new one, but I'm not a mod so I can't delete the old one.

Comment: I can take care of that bit; lemme know once the new one's up, @W5VO, so I can leave a link to it in the old one for folks who can see deleted posts ;)

Comment: @JNat I posted a new question - feel free to delete the old one.

Comment: Done, @W5VO. Thanks! ^_^

Comment: Might be fun to add back some of the old answers to figure out where the crash was.

Answer (score 1):

Makes me wonder whether one of the comments or answers on that page is crashing the client-side mathjax... there are some possible candidates...

Suggest we (temporarily?) create a *second* sandbox (not this question because we need it for meta) and trial the likely suspects there, under chrome browser... **Update: I created a draft meta question and tried each of the 22 answers, but none of them individually caused a crash. So maybe it's not an issue of bad mathjax/LaTeX code, but client-side resources being stressed?**

Went digging into the [timeline](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/434/timeline) using firefox (because in chrome it was crashing the tab *immediately after displaying the page*, which is slightly different behavior than when browsing directly to the question -- now it's displaying correclty in chrome. Hm.) Anyway here's what I see under firefox:

[image: timeline]

[image: timeline - most recently added answer 2018 Apr 24]

[image: most recently added answer 2018 Apr 24]

and also this observation about a browser crash:

[image: answer by hkBattousai]

Comment: Crashes slower for me now, but still crashes Chrome in Android